# Typescript Cannot find module in tests folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, tsconfig

I'm trying to add Jest to test my CLI written in Typescript but whenever I run `jest` it gives me the following error:

```js
Cannot find module '../src/utils' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

This is my folder structure:

```
- tests
  - utils
    - index.ts
- src
  - utils
    - index.ts
  - Profiler.ts
  - index.ts
- webpack.config.js
- jest.config.ts
- tsconfig.json
- package.jsonf
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "allowJs": false,
    "checkJs": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

This is my jest.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from "jest";
import { defaults } from "jest-config";

const config: Config = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
};

export default config;
```

May be important but VScode also throws this error
[image]

And if I click on the path to go to the file, it says file not found and displays this path
[image]

I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my `tsconfig.json`. I've tried adding both to `src` & `test` to `rootDirs` and a bunch of other things that I found online, like adding the paths to `include` but nothing has solved this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are running the test from `tests/utils/index.ts` it would be `../../src/utils`. As only going back one directory (`../`) would put you inside `tests` and then you look for a `tests/src` which does not exist

Comment: You'd think after 4 years it would be the first thing I would check... Thanks, that was it!